# Iterate through a column in R till the value of the column is at desired level

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

My data frame looks like this:

```
  a b c d Tot
1 2 3 3 2  10
2 3 4 2 3  12
3 4 2 5 3  14
4 4 3 5 1  13
```

The dput version is as follows:

```
structure(list(a = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), b = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 3L), 
    c = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 5L), d = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), Tot = c(10L, 
    12L, 14L, 13L)), .Names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "Tot"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to iterate through each row of the `Tot` column and if the value is greater than 9, I want to reduce the value of column a to 1, take the sum of row 1 again.  If the value of Tot is still greater than nine, reduce the value of column b to 1 and take the total of row 1 again.  if the value of column Tot is 9, move to the second row to repeat the process.

I tried using the While loop, for loop with an if condition, i am getting errors.  Most commonly,

```
In while (test$Tot > 9) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

For loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  if (test$Tot[i] > 9) {
    ifelse(test$a[i] > 1, 1, test$a[i])
    test$Tot[i] <- apply(test[,c(1:4)][i], 1, sum)
  }
}
```

Thought if this iteration works for the first column can extend it to subsequent columns till such time that the Tot column value is 9.  But I am getting the following error:

```
In test$Tot[i] <- apply(test[, c(1:4)][i], 1, sum) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Another version of the forloop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  if (test$Tot[i] > 9) {
    test$a[i] <- ifelse(test$a[i] > 1, 1, test$a[i])
    test$Tot[i] <- apply(test[,c(1:4)][i], 1, sum)
  }
}
```

While this changes the value of column a to 1 and and resets the value of column Tot to 9 but the sum function doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick, although it may be slow with big data:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(j in 1:(ncol(df)-1)){
    df[i, j] <- ifelse(df[i, ncol(df)] > 9, 1, df[i, j])
    df[i, ncol(df)] <- rowSums(df[i, 1:(ncol(df)-1)])
  }
}
```

Basically, you iterate through every row in the outer loop, and through every cell except `Tot` in the inner loop, and check whether `Tot` is > 10, if so set the cell to 1, recalculate `Tot` in this row, and move on to the next cell.

Result:

```
> df
  a b c d Tot
1 1 3 3 2   9
2 1 1 2 3   7
3 1 1 1 3   6
4 1 1 5 1   8
```

The code works with any amount of columns and rows, only necessity is that `Tot` is the last column in the data.